# JFreeChart: Server stops responding

Tags: java, jsp, netbeans, jfreechart

I am working on a JSP project in Netbeans. In the application, I am generating a graph using JFreeChart, which works fine.

The problem is, that after generating the graph the server stops responding, and I need to restart it to get things working again. Could this be because too many resources have been consumed by JFreeChart?

I based the application I used on code I got from [this tutorial on RoseIndia](http://www.roseindia.net/jsp/draw-statistical-chart-jsp.shtml).

Any suggestions/advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take a thread dump to check if their is any deadlock.

You can also use JProfiler or Visual VM to see what is happening with memory.